# Returning an unmodifiable reference through a member function in a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, reference

I am pretty new to C++ and I am trying to return an unmodifiable reference.
I am getting this error:

```
 __error C2365: 'NVPair<A,B>::name' : redefinition; previous definition was 'data member'
 : see declaration of 'NVPair<A,B>::name'__
```

NVPair.h

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename A, typename B>
class NVPair {

    A name;
    B value;

public:
    NVPair();
    NVPair(const A& nm, const B& vl)
    {
        name = nm;
        value = vl;
    }

     A& name() const                    
    {
        return name;
    }

     B& value() const                   
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

If you guys need more code, let me know.

Comment: Give the two data members some names different from those of member functions. Trailing underscore is a common convention, so `name_` and `value_`.

Comment: You cannot have a member variable and a function that are both named same (`name` and `value`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the naming problem, you'll also have an issue with member functions declared as const and returning non-const references to data members:

```cxx
A& get_name() const                    
{
    return name;
}

// has to be:
const A& get_name() const                    
{
    return name;
}
```